# How to refer to field from query in vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I want to do "do loop" in vba, but the condition is that the loop occurs until there is no rows in  table where "Quantity" variable is empty. But I don't knwo how to check if there are no rows like that. I tried building a query
`(SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM Table WHERE Quantity IS NULL)`,
but I don't know how to refer to this "variable" COUNT in VBA. So what I tried to do is :

```
Do 
 ....
Loop Until Count = 0
```

Please help!

Comment: Are you using DAO or ADO? If you're using DAO, see here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514372/how-do-i-save-the-result-of-an-sql-count-query-with-vba-in-access-2007

Answer (score 0):

Use `DCount`:

```vb
Count = DCount("*", "[YourTable]", "[Quantity] Is Null")
```

Comment: I tried your solution like this: Dim Count
    
`
    Count = DCount("*", "[Table]", "[Quantity] Is Null")

    Do
       DoCmd.OpenQuery "Record"
        
    Loop Until Count <> 0  ` but it didn't stop and it opened this query over and over again ad the Access crushed down. Do you see maybe where I made a mistake?

Comment: Don't know what you try to do. First `Loop Until Count = 0`, now `Loop Until Count <> 0`. Anyway, if the condition never will succeed, the loop will run forever.